# Function that modifies a tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have function in numpy:

```
def modify_vec(old_config):
    idx = np.where(old_config != 0)[0]
    remove = np.random.choice(idx)
    old_config[remove] -= 1
    increase = np.random.randint(N)
    old_config[increase] += 1
    return old_config
```

where the input is just a numpy vector of N positive integer components. What the function does is just to randomly take an index of the vector where the corresponding element is different from 0, then, it decreases that element by 1, and adds it to another element, randomly selected.

I want to do exactly the same using Tensorflow (without calling any Session), where old_config is a constant tensor of shape (1, N). I have trouble in the following. I already implemented the where in tensorflow like this:

```
idx = tf.where(tf.logical_not(tf.math.equal(old_config, tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32))))[:, 1]
```

But now, I'm having issues randomly selecting an element of this new tensor `idx`. Now, this `old_config` tensor cannot be modified because it is a constant tensor. How can I "copy" its contents to a numpy array, or how do I create another constant tensor with the modifications I expect from the function `modify_vec`? Thanks.